# display validation of child in parent view asp.net mvc 3

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

Hi every body
I am not professional in mvc3 , i have a problem for validation of child in parent view
i have a page for describing product ( called Details ) and have a partial view  for commentting on specific product ( named addUserReview )
, i use this partial view in Details view , when a user click on send button for submiting a comment if input data that user entered has problem the result displayed on  addUserReviwe page . but i want to errors display in my Details page , 
here is my code :

```
 public ActionResult AddUserReview(FormCollection form )
    {

        UserReview userReview = new UserReview();
        if(ModelState.IsValid)
        {

            TryUpdateModel(userReview);
            // check whether user is Login or not
            userReview.UserName = User.Identity.IsAuthenticated ? User.Identity.Name : Constants.AnonymousUserReviewerName;
            storeDB.UserReviews.Add(userReview);
            try{
                storeDB.SaveChanges();
            }
            catch(Exception ex )
            {

                return View();

            }
        }
        return View();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Because of you post formcollection to action you should check form properties manually.

```
ViewData.ModelState.AddModelError("XXX", form["XXX"], "XXX is wrong");
```

in View you can show error:

```
<%= Html.ValidationMessage("XXX") %>
```

But I recommend to make model and pass model to action. Not formCollection.